# Touch screen for projecting results and mentoring PhD students: a good solution for a computer lab?

Tags: teaching, computer-science, technology

I just got an assistant professor position in the USA. I am negotiating the startup package. I am mainly doing computational staff (engineering deparment) therefore I am asking for computing nodes in the campus HPC facility and for a small local cluster to put in my relatively small computer lab, where initially 2 PhD students will work (and more in the future + post-docs). I would like to add a nice touch screen, probably around 40 inches or more in which I can project powerpoint presentations and simulation results, and which could be also used as a board by means of a pen or fingers. It would be nice to explain things to my group by drawing on the screen and then saving the notes directly on a file. Which one is the best solution for my needs? I see that there are:

1. LED Interactive Displays
2. Whiteboards
3. Interactive Projectors

Which are the differences? Which option is best? I was thinking of a LED display. What I am looking for is:

- multiple finger touch
- touch screen feature has to work also if projecting my laptop screen (and any other pc in the lab) to the big display by cable
- possible to project screen of any other computer in the lab via wifi, and touch screen would still be available (optional)
- the display has a little processor and hard drive, with windows installed (optional, maybe not really necessary?)

I guess here is not the right place to suggest brands, but it is possible please go ahead, otherwise general indications are fine.

Comment: In most of the places I've worked in, this thing will work for a week, then will be down most of the time because no one knows how to run the maintenance for unusual devices. Are you sure this will not happen at your office?

Comment: Have you considered a (good-quality) tablet pc with digitizer pen setup, connected to a beamer? It gives essentially the same results, but it seems vastly cheaper and easier to handle to me.

Comment: In Europe many university has ctouch, its 24000euros (very expensive), and its beautiful, they have on-site assistance for 7 years (https://ctouch.eu/classroom/ , in the video it is shown how students can throw the screen of their laptop to the big screen with a gesture). I saw it myself, very impressive. However they dont sell in USA. I was looking for something similar.

Comment: From the ctouch website "Every CTOUCH display ships with a single Smoothboard licence that
allows up to 40 wireless devices to be connected at any one time.
Smoothboard allows collaboration between iPads, Android tablets,
laptops and smartphones, across all platforms (Windows, Mac,
Linux). Teachers and presenters, classes and audiences can now
engage like never before."  Thats even too much for my small lab, I would say something cheaper that can connect fewer device would be enough